# No module named django-admin

Tags: python, django, cmd, django-admin

estoy empezando un curso de Django, en un momento del video, me dice que tengo que poner el siguiente codigo "python -m django-admin starproject Proyecto1", pero a mi me da el siguiente error al ejecutarlo en la cmd
"python.exe: No module named django-admin"
¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?.

Les dejo el link del video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2DbWqyBR4Oo&ab_channel=pildorasinformaticas

Desde el minuto 7:50

Comment: Un pip install django?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes resolver el problema si escribes el directorio completo en el que se ubica tu archivo django-admin.py

```
python C:\Python37\Scripts\django-admin.py startproject mysite
```